# unhandledpromisedrejectionwarning: typeerror: cannot read property 'voice' of null

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make it so my discord bot will send a message to a user if the command is used in a DM channel and not a server channel. But this segment of code does not work, it throws an error when used. Any tips?

```js
        if (command === 'join'){
            if(message.channel.type === 'dm'){
            message.author.send("You need to be in a voice channel in a server to use this command. ");
            }else{
            const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
            const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
            if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a voice channel to use this command. ');
            if (!permissions.has('CONNECT')) return message.channel.send("You don't have permission to do that");
            if (!permissions.has('SPEAK')) return message.channel.send("You don't have permission to do that");
            voiceChannel.join();
            }
        }
```

Comment: `message.member` is null - is your question "why is this bill"?

Answer (score -1):

Since you have not specified what version of discord.js you are using I show an answer for discord.js v13 and v12.

#### v13

In v13, if so `dm` is not a valid type of channel it instead should be `DM`, additionally, you should `return` inside the if block so that the rest of the code is not executed if inside of a dm channel.

```js
if (command === 'join') {
    if (message.channel.type === 'DM') {
        return message.author.send('You need to be in a voice channel in a server to use this command. ');
    } 
    /* ... */
}
```

#### v12

In discord.js v12 `dm` is a valid channel type so all you would have to do is make sure to `return` to stop code execution after warning the user.

```js
if (command === 'join') {
    if (message.channel.type === 'dm') {
        return message.author.send('You need to be in a voice channel in a server to use this command. ');
    } 
    /* ... */
}
```